# Prerequisites for developing for iPad iOS 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Seems like every time i go thru a required update of either the mac OS or the device iOS, i always end up getting very frustrated to the point of giving up on the iphone/ipad development altogether.

I just recently bought an ipad2 (iOS 5.1.1). And i noticed that my old Xcode 4 didnt support this iOS version. So now I just upgraded to XCode 4.2. But now I am still required to downgrade the iPad2 iOS to 5.0 (unfortunately). Now if I wanted to develop for iOS 5.1, then I must upgrade to XCode 4.3.2, which means I also need to upgrade my OS to Lion (i currently have Snow Leopard).

I believe these are the prerequisites that i was able to straighten out. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Finally, if my assessment here is correct, then I do need to download the iOS 5.0 firmware. I am unable to find a link to this anywhere on apple's site (everything is for 5.1). Anybody know where i can get the download link for older iOS's ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to your Xcode organizer, could you connect your iPad and select "Use For development" button that appears with your device in the organizer?

If the answer is "yes", then you can develop for iOS 4 and just do your testing on your iPad running OS 5.1.1.

If the answer is "no", then you should update your Macintosh to Lion and your Xcode to 4.3.X (which will include the iOS 5.0 & 5.1 SDK).

If you want to "downgrade" your iPad to iOS 5.0 (and good luck with that), [you can find a download link in this article](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-5.0.1-ios-9a406-for-iphone-4s-direct-link/).

But don't stress too much.  Once you get accustomed to development, you can hopefully keep up with the times (and the frequent OS & Xcode updates) pretty easily.

Comment: i do remember seeing this button somewhere. i clicked it of course. but i think i had to stop the moment i tried to deploy to the device i think. ill have to go back and confirm my steps.

Comment: I just bought the latest OSX Lion (off of appstore). Then i downloaded/installed the latest XCode. Then (surprisingly) getting a bare-bones iPad app running on simulator was a piece of cake (it also deployed perfectly fine on my iPad as well). This was a pleasant surprise as I always had some complication in previous XCode iterations.